# Возможно ли в C++ в качестве параметра шаблона как-то задать поле класса/структуры?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как известно, параметрами шаблона в C++ могут быть типы данных, константы, указатели... А существует ли способ каким-либо образом параметризовать идентификаторы полей классов или структур? Вот пример, иллюстрирующий мой вопрос:

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct TEST_STRUC
{
    int a;
    int b;

    TEST_STRUC(int val_a, int val_b): a(val_a), b(val_b) {}
};


template </*как-то определяем параметр-поле*/ F, class TClass>
void PrintCompare(TClass* pCls1, TClass* pCls2)
{
    if (pCls1->F > pCls2->F) puts("Greater than");
    else if (pCls1->F < pCls2->F) puts("Lower than");
    else puts("Equal");
}


//.............

int main()
{
    TEST_STRUC t1(7,4), t2(8,2);

    PrintCompare<a>(&t1, &t2);
    PrintCompare<b>(&t1, &t2);

    return 0;
}
```

Сразу оговорюсь: вариант замены полей на массив (и использование константных параметров-индексов, вместо полей) не интересен.

Comment: Вы ищите [указатели на члены?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/670734/2752075) А в шаблон передавать как `auto F`.

Comment: @LShadow77, то,  что вы хотите, поясняет, что вы забыли, что шаблоны  плохо использовать там, где не  намечается полиморфизм времени компиляции.  Вам как раз  нужен полиморфизм времени выполнения, так как вы пытаетесь решить задачу с типами, имеющие какую то логичную связь, то есть все  объекты, которые будут переданы в эту функцию, должны иметь  подобный член.  Лично я, даже не попытался бы думать о решении такого не  внушающего доверия  вопроса....

Comment: imho для решения такой задачи прекрасно подходят макросы

Comment: А предложенный HolyBlackCat [способ](https://godbolt.org/z/nsTKcxPrf) почему не интересен?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan как раз мне нужен полиморфизм времени компиляции. По-этому шаблоны тут весьма подходят. Тем более, что в конкретной задаче, которую мне надо решить, все функции/методы в шаблонах - полностью инлайновые.

Comment: @avp я рассматривал этот вариант, как выход, если подходящего решения с шаблонами не будет найдено. Однако это достаточно кривой подход, т.к. имеет недостатки, свойственные макросам.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо - это очень похоже на то, что мне требуется. Добавил ответ с модифицированным примером, буду рад замечаниям.

Comment: @LShadow77, да, макросы (*"автомобиль это страшное оружие в руках молодого бойца"*) не предоставляют того количестве проверок, что делает компилятор

Comment: @avp именно! И в namespace их не загонишь, и в друзья класса не добавишь...

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо за комменты! Вариант, наиболее близкий к тому, что мне нужен, - это предложенный @HolyBlackCat, с указателями на члены. В общем, пока что я пришёл к подходу, который иллюстрирует код ниже. Насколько он удачен, покажет решение моей конкретной задачи. Совсем без макросов обойтись не получилось, т.к. "чистый" синтаксис вышел уж больно многословный. Буду рад комментариям с замечаниями и предложениями по улучшению подобного кода...

```
#include <stdio.h>


template <class TClass, int TClass::*F>
class Mgr
{
public:
    static void PrintCompare(TClass* pCls1, TClass* pCls2)
    {
        if (pCls1->*F > pCls2->*F) puts("Greater than");
        else if (pCls1->*F < pCls2->*F) puts("Lower than");
        else puts("Equal");
    }
};

#define FRIEND_MGR              template <class TClass, int TClass::*F> friend class Mgr 
#define USE_MGR(class,field)    typedef Mgr<class, &class::field>


class CTestClass
{
    FRIEND_MGR;

    int a;
    int b;

public:
    USE_MGR(CTestClass, a) MgrA;
    USE_MGR(CTestClass, b) MgrB;

    CTestClass(int val_a, int val_b): a(val_a), b(val_b) {}
};


int main()
{
    CTestClass t1(7,4), t2(8,2);

    CTestClass::MgrA::PrintCompare(&t1, &t2);
    CTestClass::MgrB::PrintCompare(&t1, &t2);

    return 0;
}
```